# For datetype BIT, is | faster than OR?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given that X & Y are datetype bit

`WHERE Something = 1 AND ( X = 1 OR Y= 1 )`

`WHERE Something = 1 AND X | Y = 1`

Is the second one, that uses |, faster than the OR above? If so, why?

My co-worker is saying they are. I'm kinda dumb, and also lazy, and am trying to confirm that's true, before I try to understand why.

We use T-SQL, though I imagine whatever the answer it, it's probably universal to most (all?) flavors of SQL?

Comment: As to what's faster: that's answered by inspecting execution plans and/or actually timing the queries that use these operators (hint: most of the time will not be taken by these operations, but by whatever I/O the query needs and whether or not indexes can be used). As to assuming the answer is in any way "universal": no, noooo. Aside from database engines not using the same dialects of SQL, they certainly don't use the same *implementations*. Results obtained on one engine do not translate to another, except for *very* general observations like "an index helps".

Comment: They aren't the same if one of them is null. Even in the cases that they do have the same semantics the `AND X | Y = 1` is less likely to produce accurate cardinality estimates than the less obfuscated `or` version which could cause worse execution plans in some cases. Go for readability `WHERE Something = 1 AND 1 IN (X,Y)`

Comment: Suggested reading: [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/) and [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages, bit-fiddling is a way to save storage and increase performance. Although storing items as bits can save storage in a relational database, it is not a route to improved performance.

Basically, bit operators -- as with most other functions and operators -- impede the optimizer and prevent the use of indexes and partition pruning. They also generally incur a bit of overhead, just because CPUs are designed to handle bunches of bits at a time (think 4-bytes or 8-bytes) rather than individual bits.

Then there is the question of what performance would be saved. If the query is doing a full table scan, *the primary cost is reading the data*. Not filtering the data. In the time it takes to read a data page into memory, lots and lots and lots and lots of comparisons on bits or integers can be made -- way more than 3 per row.

So, even if there were a difference in performance, it would be very hard to measure. I do encourage you to try. I would imagine that the two versions are essentially equivalent, each having three bit operations and some booleans thrown in.